# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' after imported BrowserModule

Tags: angular

Before marking this question as duplicate, I've read all related questions asked before, but my problem is still.

- I've 3 custom modules, all have **CommonModule** imported
- I've imported all my custom modules to **app.module.ts**
- I've imported **BrowserModule** in **app.module.ts**
- As optional, I've imported **CommonModule** to **app.module.ts** besides **BrowserModule**, but nothing changed
- I am using ***ngIf**, not ***ngif**
- I've rebuilt the project, restarted the IDE

It is still giving me **Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.** error.

```
//app.module.ts
imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    CustomModule1,
    CustomModule2,
    CustomModule3
]

//custom1.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    ContactUsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PublicRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ]
})

//home.component.html
<div class="container mt-2" *ngIf="registerMode">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <app-register (cancelRegister) = "cancelRegisterMode($event)"></app-register>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the component in which you are putting `*ngIf` located in a module that has `CommonModule` imported? Where exactly are you using the `*ngIf` respective to the modules?

Comment: @RubenSzekér, Yep my component is located in the related module that has CommonModule imported.

Comment: @YSFKBDY Can you post the code?

Comment: Try importing `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: hey!!! Try importing **ngModule**

Comment: Had the same issue. Fixed it by stopping the `ng serve` process and starting it again.